# How to raise to the power of an exponent?

Tags: javascript, math

How can I calculate *98 raised to the power of exp(13-5)* using JavaScript?

Is this the way?

```
Math.pow(98,Math.exp(8))
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  When I run it [here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTuhE/) it returns "_Infinity_".

Comment: If you're trying to raise 98 to the exponent of the Euler's constant to the 8th, then yes. But, that's probably going to give you "Infinity" in most JS environments. ;)

Comment: Yep... Now that I see what _Math.exp_ is, you're trying to raise 98 to the "_almost 3,000th power_".... so you're talking about a number that's pretty huge.  So... You're performing the math correctly, but JavaScript's number system is not able to represent the result as a number.  Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/778118) for some info about the largest number JavaScript can represent.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I think I am not getting the numbers right, which are again derived from different formulas. I will check and post back here

Comment: another question I have is...is ln(x) same as Math.log(x)?

Answer (score 0):

When I need to handle large positive numbers that would overflow standard floating point types  then I store the numbers as log of the number instead.  So instead of calculating 98 to the power of exp(8), I'd calculate exp(8) * log(98) and work with that.  I haven't (yet) come across a situation where even that method was inadequate to store the numbers that I needed.  However, I have come across several situations where the right answer involves multiplying very very large numbers by very very small numbers, and in that situation using logs as I described has avoided overflows/underflows which would result in the wrong answer.

Update: I suspect this is some kind of homework question relating to how to get round the problem that 98 ^ exp(8) is too big for standard floating point types.  In which case, I think my suggestion to use logs comes in handy.  For example, to print out the number in C# you could do the following:

```
double x = Math.Exp(13 - 5) * Math.Log(98);  // the number required is exp(x)
int exponent = (int)Math.Floor(x / Math.Log(10));
double absissae = Math.Exp(x - exponent * Math.Log(10));
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(absissae.ToString() + " E " + exponent.ToString());
```

which produces the output

```
5.77130918514205 E 5935
```